# manipulate div content using simple_html_dom

Tags: php, jquery, simple-html-dom

test01.php

```
<div id="res"></div>
```

I need to change the content of `#res` on server side.

ajax.php

```
include ("simple_html_dom.php");  // the same folder as `ajax.php`
$url = $_POST["url"];  // http://localhost/up/matria/test01.php - that's ok
$html = file_get_html($url);
$html->find('div#res')->innertext = '525';
```

To save changes I tried:

```
$html->save($url);  // first try
file_put_contents($url, $html);  // next try
$htmlString = $html->save();
file_put_contents($url);  // next try
```

Reloading the page - `res` is still empty.

Comment: Are you trying to then save the manipulated html back to test01.php or are you trying to just send the manipulated html back to a browser?  I am not seeing either in the ajax.php above.

Comment: @DustinSimpson, I need to save the new content and reloading the page to see `#res`  content changed.

Comment: Hopefully my answer below is what you are looking for.  Let me know if I missed the mark completely or can help more.

Comment: @DustinSimpson, I tried your solutions, plus one solution of my own - without success. Please see update of my post

Comment: you won't be able to save to the $url.  You will have to save to the path to the file on disk.  So like /var/www/html/up/matria/test01.php or whatever.

Comment: @DustinSimpson, it works now, `rest` is changed, but as a result entire `test01`page is written in pure html, without `php include code`, without  line breaks and so on. Is there a way to keep my original structure of page, pls.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103538/discussion-between-dustin-simpson-and-bonaca).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you change the innertext, go ahead and save the html back to the file

Like:

```
$html->save(path to file on disk);
```

Alternatively you can get the html string back and save it using PHP file system functions:

```
$htmlString = $html->save();
file_put_contents(path to file on disk);
```